# jQuery/Javascript splitting string calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, character

I'm creating a product page that requires the price to update when the quantity value is changed. Two form fields are used: `.orig_price` and `#quantity`. These values are obviously multiplied together.

I'm trying to split the multiplied value, so that I can print the correct format (27.7043454575 should be 27.70).

My code:

```
jQuery("#quantity").change(function() {

         jQuery("#pricediv").hide();

// store form values
         var origprice = jQuery(".orig_price").val().substr(1); 
         var qty = jQuery("#quantity").val();

// calculate price
         var sumValue = origprice * qty;

// split price
         var splitprice = sumValue.split("."); 
         var pricepound = splitprice[0];
         var pricepenny = splitprice[1].substring(0,2);   

// update price

         jQuery("#pricediv").html('&pound;' + pricepound + '.' + pricepenny);
         jQuery("#pricediv").fadeIn(1500);
});
```

If I remove the split and use `sumValue` everything works (but format is wrong). Does split not work on a calculation?

Comment: In addition to the great answer underneath it might be worth adding that the problem with your approach was that `sumValue` is a number (because of the multiplication that happened beforehand) so you cannot apply a String method like `split`. `String(sumValue).split(".");` would work

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Why not floats when dealing with currency? How else are you going to compute a percentage tax, for instance, if not with floating-point math?

Comment: @mblase75 Because floats are imprecise by nature? It's better to work with whole pennies where possible (and it's certainly possible in the OP's code).

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Floats are imprecise, yes, but typically not until the tenth decimal place or thereabouts. I've never heard this argument from anyone else and can't think of a single good example. If you're using division or percentages AT ALL in your arithmetic, floating-point math is a necessity. All you need to do is round off to the correct decimal value at every step in the computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use `sumValue.toFixed(2)`

```
var sumValue = 27.7043454575;
sumValue.toFixed(2) // 27.70
```

`.split` does not exist on numeric types. You would have to use `sumValue.toString().split('.')`, and either way, this would be more inconvenient than simply sticking to `.toFixed`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toFixed` and `parseInt()` like so:

```
jQuery("#quantity").change(function() {

         jQuery("#pricediv").hide();

// store form values
         var origprice = parseInt(jQuery(".orig_price").val().substr(1),10); 
         var qty = parseInt(jQuery("#quantity").val(),10);

// calculate price
         var sumValue = origprice * qty;

// split price
         var price = sumValue.toFixed(2);  

// update price

         jQuery("#pricediv").html('&pound;' + price);
         jQuery("#pricediv").fadeIn(1500);
});
```

`toFixed` determines the number of points after a decimal, and `parseInt` type-casts the input to an integer (the 10 is unnecessary but there to show it's decimal base 10), because when getting data from a form field it sometimes comes back as a string and messes up your math.